# PyQt4 - link the extent of a slider to the extent of a plotting axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, autoscaling, sliders

Using PyQt4 and matplotlib how can I link the extent (i.e. length) of a slider to the extent of a plot axis in the same window, such that the slider has the same length as the plot axis even when the window is rescaled?

Comment: This a Qt slider or a mpl.widgets slider?

Comment: @fen Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the limits of an axis in a `matplotlib` plot using `ax.get_xlim()` or `ax.get_ylim()`. These returns a `tuple` containing minimum and maximum value for that axis in *data coordinates*. The advantage of using data coordinates is that they remain the same, no matter the scaling of the plot.

Helpfully Qt auto-scales the range of a `QSlider` to put the min/max values at the limit of the slider. Therefore, you can simply use the axis limit values to set the range for the `QSlider` to get a 1:1 relationship between the position of the slider and the position on the axis.

```
 xlims = ax.get_xlim()  # e.g. (0, 200)

 slider = QSlider()
 slider.setRange(*xlims)  # unpack the tuple into setRange
                          # alternatively slider.setRange(xlims[0], xlims[1])
```